# Удаление строки из ListView

Tags: android-sdk, android, listview, java

Происходит Fatal Error при обработке данного кода:

```
String lv_arr[] = new String[key];
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterlist = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
    lv_arr);
listView1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
listView1.setAdapter(adapterlist);
adapterlist.notifyDataSetChanged();
adapterlist.remove(adapterlist.getItem(0));
adapterlist.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: кинь лог, что тут должно работать?

Comment: где вызывается данный код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется мне надо делать так, сразу после инициализации

```
adapterlist.setNotifyOnChange(true)
```

Он автоматически оповестит, при изменении

**upd** кажется это не решает проблему, будем копать дальше

Comment: так решать нечего, он пытается удалить первый элемент списка а потом это показать.... даже если бы все работало, он бы особо нечего не заметил..

Comment: дак ListView не обновляется (первый элемент должен пропасть). Как же многое сыро в андроиде :( Ладно удаление, он наверно и на добавление не сработает

Comment: кинь код своего примера полностью

Comment: @Gorets это обращение к ТС? Вы тоже думаете что не в UI-thread идет вызов метода?

Answer (score 0):

Надо удалить элемент из списка адаптера:

```
adapterlist.remove(0);
```

А не пытаться удалить имеющийся уже в адаптере элемент из самого `ListView`...

Comment: [remove(T object][1]

 [1]:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#remove%28T%29

Comment: adpterlist.remove (String object);

Answer (score 0):

удали значение из lv_arr[]. Оно удалится из листвью